# Sunspot Solr partial search working in development but not in production after deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am using sunspot solr for free text searching. I am trying to search trader from trader model. Here is the searchable block

```
searchable do
  text :name
  text :postcode
  text :phone
  text :phone_alt
  text :phone_mobile
end
```

Here is the schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="20" side="front"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="20" side="back"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="20" side="front"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="20" side="back"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And here is controller code

```
 search = Trader.search do
      keywords params[:q] do
          minimum_match 2
        end
    end
    @traders = search.results
```

Lets say I have two trader in my trader model. There name is 'Gryffindor Hall' and 'Ravenclaw Halls'. When I search using 'Hall' in development i get both of this trader. After deploying in production, for the same query string it returns only the 1st trader. Which is not right. Actually where is the problem?

Comment: It might be worth rebuilding your index. If you remove the data folder for Solr and then stop/start it, it should rebuild it.

Comment: I have reindexed it. Didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention anything about your production environment, but if you deploy to heroku you must edit the websolr schema.xml as it ignores your local schema.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact problem and was able to solve it by running the following on the production server.  First stop solr...

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:stop
```

Then I removed the solr directory from my project (`rm -rf solr`) and reinstalled with...

```
rails generate sunspot_rails:install
```

After this, edit your `/solr/conf/schema.xml` to have the partial search.  Restart the application server and solr as well as reindex your models.

Hope this helps!